# Association with same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a `City` model which I would like to set up an optional relationship with another city known as a sister city. In order to avoid adding another column to `cities` I would like to create a join table that holds the association.

```
create_table :sister_city_mappings do |t|
  t.integer :city_id
  t.integer :sister_city_id

  t.timestamps null: false
end

class City
  has_one :sister_city_mapping, :class_name => 'SisterCityMapping', 
  foreign_key: :city_id
  has_one :sister_city, :class_name => 'City', through: 
  :sister_city_mapping, source: :sister_city
end

class SisterCityMapping
  belongs_to :city, :class_name => 'City'
  belongs_to :sister_city, :class_name => 'City',
  foreign_key: :sister_city_id
end
```

This kind of works as I can do `City.first.sister_city = City.last` but I can not handle the relationship through form params as cleanly as I'd like:

```
City.first.sister_city_id = 2
NoMethodError: undefined method `sister_city_id=' for #<City:0x007f893be1b178>
```

and trying:

```
City.first.sister_city = 2
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: City(#70113697769780) expected, got Fixnum(#70113638622260)
```

I think it's very likely that the associations are incorrect, I have also tried  `SisterCityMapping has_one :sister_city` but haven't been successful.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid adding another column to `cities`?

Comment: @lysdexic This started out as a challenge to myself that I've just gotten more stuck on than I expected. At this point I'd just like to learn an alternate pattern to solve this problem than simply 'put a column on it'.

Comment: Check out my answer, if you want to do it the way you've set it up you just need to pass it a City object instead of the id directly

Comment: The issue is that when I have a form for a `City` I would like to select another city through a drop down and handle the association through `@city.update(params)` using the id of the sister_city. I will not have the instance available. I understand your suggestion but it is specifically not the implementation I am aiming for.

Comment: But you have the id of the sister city, why not use that to find the sister city with `City.find(params[:id]`.  If you don't even want to do that you could maybe do `City.first.sister_city_mapping.create(sister_city_id: params[:id])`

Answer (score 0):

You really should just add a sister_city_id column to your cities table:

```
class City
  has_one :sister_city, :class_name => 'City'
end
```

If you really want to use this join table association, you can create the relation like this:

`City.first.sister_city = City.find(2)`

Comment: This is not correct - has_one would place the foreign key column on the other model (City), so this would either end up as an endless loop or not work at all.